# Rails 3: has_many :throught save problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I was hoping someone could explain to me why i can't save new record?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :viewed_posts, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :posts, :through => :viewed_posts

    def update_viewed_posts(post)
        if viewed_posts.where("id IN(?)", post.id).blank?
            puts '----------------------- NEVER READED POST'
            viewed_posts.build(:question_id => post.id, :user_id=> self.id)
        end
    end
end

class ViewedPosts < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
end
```

My question is when i call `update_view_posts` method record is never save? Why?
**EDITED:** Added my controller. I'm calling `update_view_posts` on show action.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html

    before_filter :find_post, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
        if current_user
            current_user.update_viewed_posts(@post)
        end
    respond_with(@post)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want:

```
belongs_to :post
```

instead of

```
belongs_to :posts
```

Comment: I make mistake. It's not posts. It's post.Any idea?

Comment: Try changing it to "viewed_posts.build(:question_id => post.id)", since it should know the user id automagically.

Comment: Also, I think the user needs to be saved before the build can work.

Comment: @Tim can you post a example? please

Comment: The only other thing I can think of, is name your class "ViewedPost" instead of "ViewedPosts", models are usually singular.

Comment: So, you'd create your user, e.g. user1, and eventually do "user1.save".  After that, then you can call "user1.update_viewed_posts(post1)".  The save might be necessary to do before calling the method that has the build.

Comment: Added my controller. I'm calling update_viewed_posts method on show action.